# Laptop wifi works great when unplugged but plugging it in causes wifi to slow

Tags: networking, 22.04, laptop, iwlwifi

As the title states my wifi is being weird. I have Googled around for a while now but have not found a solution. I have tried `sudo iwconfig wlo1 power off` and changing the line `wifi.powersave = 3` in `/etc/Network Manager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` to `wifi.powersave = 2`. I have tried restarting, moving closer to the router, and testing the network from other devices. I do not have an ethernet cable (yet) to test with.

Output of `sudo lshw -C network` (when plugged in or unplugged) is:

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 04:d3:b0:ab:82:8b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-43-generic firmware=46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- ip=192.168.2.143 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:a4414000-a4417fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: 30:9c:23:fe:34:2a
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=5.19.0-43-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:a4200000-a423ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

And output of

```
interface=$(nmcli -t -f active,device d wifi list | grep '^yes' | cut -d':' -f2)
echo -e "\n        \033[1;33mInterface:\033[0m $interface"
signal_strength=$(iw dev $interface link | awk '/signal/ {print $2}')
echo -e "        \033[1;33mSignal strength:\033[0m $signal_strength"
signal_quality=$(nmcli d wifi list ifname $interface | grep '*' | awk '{print $8}')
echo -e "        \033[1;33mSignal quality:\033[0m $signal_quality"
signal_bars=$(nmcli -t -f active,bars d wifi list | grep '^yes' | awk -F: '{print $2}')
echo -e "        \033[1;33mSignal bars:\033[0m $signal_bars"
speed=$(nmcli -t -f IN-USE,RATE dev wifi list | grep '*' | awk -F: '{print $2}')
echo -e "        \033[1;33mWi-Fi Speed:\033[0m $speed"
channel=$(nmcli -t -f IN-USE,CHAN dev wifi list | grep '*' | awk -F: '{print $2}')
echo -e "        \033[1;33mWi-Fi Channel:\033[0m $channel"
noise=$(awk 'NR==3 {print "Link: " $3 " Level: " $4 " Noise: " $5}' /proc/net/wireless)
echo -e "        \033[1;33mWi-Fi Noise, Link and Quality Level:\033[0m $noise";
```

when unplugged is:

```
        Interface: wlo1
        Signal strength: -66
        Signal quality: Mbit/s
        Signal bars: ▂▄▆_
        Wi-Fi Speed: 540 Mbit/s
        Wi-Fi Channel: 44
        Wi-Fi Noise, Link and Quality Level: Link: 44. Level: -66. Noise: -256
```

and when plugged in is:

```
        Interface: wlo1
        Signal strength: -63
        Signal quality: Mbit/s
        Signal bars: ▂▄▆_
        Wi-Fi Speed: 540 Mbit/s
        Wi-Fi Channel: 44
        Wi-Fi Noise, Link and Quality Level: Link: 46. Level: -64. Noise: -256
```

Edit:
Thanks to waltinator's suggestion to use `sudo journalctl  --follow` I was able to diagnose and find a solution. This command revealed that I was having a repeated Microcode SW error. Googling the error brought me to [this page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=265159), the solution at the bottom to change `/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters` to  `11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=0 uapsd_disable=1` seems to have solved my issue.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you unplug/wait 5 sec/plug/wait 5 sec/`^C` to get a hint. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment, or you'll classify yourself as "Does Not Follow Instructions (DNFI)", and I'll ignore you. I view DNFIs as unhelpable.

Comment: @waltinator, thanks for the suggestion. I was able to figure out a solution and have edited my question with the solution that I found. Cheers!